# Android Emulator is running but not loading my app in Titanium

Tags: android, titanium, emulation

I can run the app in the "mobile app preview in browser", and I can boot up the Android Emulator successfully. But the emulator just showed me the home screen all the time without loading my app. I've looked through all the similar questions online but couldn't find a solution.

Here is the console...hope someone can help me out. Thanks!

```
*Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.1.0, Titanium SDK version 3.1.0.GA
Copyright (c) 2012-2013, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
[INFO] :   Running emulator process: python "C:\Users\Ni\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.0.GA\android\builder.py" "emulator" "myFirstApp" "C:\Users\Ni\Android-sdk\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk" "C:\Users\Ni\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\myFirstApp" "com.yn.myFirstApp" "4" "HVGA" "armeabi"
[INFO] :   Running build process:  python "C:\Users\Ni\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.0.GA\android\builder.py" "simulator" "myFirstApp" "C:\Users\Ni\Android-sdk\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk" "C:\Users\Ni\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\myFirstApp" "com.yn.myFirstApp" "4" "HVGA"
[INFO] logfile = C:\Users\Ni\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\myFirstApp\build.log
[INFO] Building myFirstApp for Android ... one moment
[INFO] Titanium SDK version: 3.1.0 (04/15/13 18:45 57634ef)
[INFO] :   Emulator process exited successfully
[INFO] :   Project built successfully in 3s 24ms
[INFO] :   Emulator not running, exiting...*
```

Comment: The Android emulator and Titanium Studio appear to have trouble connecting with each other some times.  For me, closing the emulator or attempting to run the project 2-3 times sometimes fixed the issues for me.  Are you allowing Titanium to load up the emulator for you?

Comment: Martin, thank you for the reply. I run the project several times but the emulator still doesn't load the app. I run the Titanium as administrator so it should allow Titanium to load up the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add an answer for this question...
I could successfully run the Titanium only when I choose "run as administrator".

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you have solved this, but for the reference of others, you shouldn't run the emulator yourself, allow Titanium Studio to launch the emulator by simply running your application with the emulator option (like Martin says)

In my own experience, i'm able to run my app in the emulator, but for all subsequent runs, i need to close the emulator and run the app again since Studio fails to detect the emulator and gives me an error similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

When this happens, you can install the app manually.
You will find your app's executable in the following directory under your app directory: build/android/bin/YOURAPPNAME.apk. On the Mac, you need to open a terminal window, cd to that directory, and type "chmod 777 YOURAPPNAME.apk". Then cd to the platform-tools directory under your android sdk installation directory, and run the following commands:

```
./adb kill-server
./adb start-server
./adb install <full path name to YOURAPPNAME.apk>
```

You will see your app appear on the home screen of the emulator.

I made a shell script to do this.